# Is it theoretically possible transfer thermal energy to electrical?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermoelectricity

I was searching web trying to find answer, but all I found are thermoelectrical generators which work on principle flowing electrons from heat to cold material and efficient is very low.

I am wondering is it theoretically possible that there could be a some sort of chemicals which in combination would create positive and negative terminals, so when there is a load connected to those terminals, chemicals would become colder and thus transfer thermal energy into electrical?

Comment: A steam turbine does a fine job of converting thermal to electrical. You are going to need to refine this. Also, search on 'thermal battery'.

Comment: Short answer, No. There is no way to suck the heat out of something and turn it into electric power. The only way to use heat energy is to extract energy from the _flow_ of heat from a heat source to a heat sink. I am not going to make this an "answer" though because I am not a physicist, and I can't give you a good explanation of _why_ heat works that way.

Comment: @Jon, steam turbine need heatsink, for example river near power plant. Solomon correctly understood what I am asking, but I would like to know why is that impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a [thermocouple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermocouple), which operates on the [Seebeck effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_effect#Seebeck_effect) does that.

Comment: This is a thermoelectric generator.

Comment: Alright. That might be the case. The term "generator" indicates the generation of power, though, which only the Seebeck effect does. The Peltier effect is rather *provided* with a power to create a temperature difference.

Comment: @Steeven, yes, you're right. I deleted my comment.

Comment: But, we need heatsink for Seeback effect, I meant directly without colder heatsink.

Comment: @Shiro, You always need a temperature difference to extract energy from a thermal source. Google Carnot's Theorem.